# How to get the square root of a big number as returned by web3.utils.toBN()?

Tags: web3js, bignumber, math

I'm working with big numbers as returned by web3.utils.toBN(). According to the web3 documentation, this function returns a BN.js instance. However, there doesn't seem to be a square root function on BN.js according to its documentation (https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/).

What is the best way to get the square root of a BN.js number?